# Laravel file upload not working: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string

Tags: axios, single-page-application, laravel-5.8

I am trying to upload a file from an input field. I have the following fields:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <input id="item" class="form-control-file my-2 w-100" type="file">
 </td>
 <td>
  <input id="remark" class="form-control my-2 w-100" type="text">
 </td>
</tr>
```

Then my axios post:

```
self.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/item/new', {
 batchcode: document.getElementById("batchcode_form").value, // is somewhere else in the code, works fine.
 product_code: document.getElementById("item").files[0].name,
 remark: document.getElementById("item"),
 input_type: 'item'
}).then(function (response) {
 if (response.data.status === 'success') {
 // success
} else {
 // failed
}
});
```

The headers are displaying the following data:

> batchcode "batchcode i filled in"
>
> input_type: "file"
>
> product_code: "filenamewithoutpath.png"
>
> remark: "remark i filled in"

Now I have the following code in my itemscontroller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->product_code != "" && $request->remark != "") {
            // create item
            $item = new Item;
            $item->batchcode = $request->batchcode;
            $item->remarks = $request->remark;
            if ($request->input_type === "file") {
                // upload file
                $file = $request->product_code;
                $item->product_code = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $new_name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $path = public_path() . '/uploads/';
                $file->move($path, $new_name);
                $item->product_code = '/uploads/' . $new_name;
            } else {
            $item->product_code = $request->product_code;
            }
            $item->save();
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'data' => $item
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'data' => 'Not all data was given.'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

When I execute this I get the following error:
`Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string`

I get the correct filename, but the upload part isn't working. I can't figure out or find anything on google why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). Example:

```
let payload = new FormData()
```

And then add the fields to the form you want to send :

```
payload.set('input_type', 'item')
```

If you are uploading images or files, you may want to use .append

```
payload.append('remark', imageFile);
```

And then you can use axios post method (You can amend it accordingly)

```
self.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/item/new', payload, {
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
})
.then(function (response) {
    //handle success
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (response) {
    //handle error
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.
May I ask where you get the `bodyFormData` from?